# Notepad to .py file

Tags: windows-10, python, file-conversion

When I first made a .py file I told it to open in notepad, and now it wont run in cmd, it only opens the notepad, does anybody have a fix for that?.
I thought that i was supossed to run it by dobble clicking it to run in cmd (i know its stupid but i did it) and then i pressed open in notepad (and of course i pressed open this with notepad or something like that) and now i cant get it back [picture for help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tejtE.png)
System is windows 10,

My first language is not english so please say so if you dont understand everything
Sorry for such a noobish question, all answers are apreciated, and thank you in advanced.

Comment: You need to explain what you did to make it open in notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd> Click on a .py file in explorer and selecting "open with..." and then manually selecting the python interpreter.

And there is another checkbox that asks whether to use the settings for all files of this type, you should check that.

Also, make sure your PATH (system/user environment variable) includes the path to your python executable.